# How to redefine a string and give it a randomized value from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, random

The code goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string taijutsu;
    string ninjutsu;
    string eyes;
    string chakra;
    string summoning;
    string iq;
    string speed;

    string people[] = {"Sasuke", "Itachi", "Madara", "Naruto", "Minato","Ino", "Rock Lee", "Might guy", "Kakashi", "Tsunade", "Hashirama", "Sakura", "Gaara", "Hinata", "Shikamaru", "Pain", "Obito", "Jiraiya", "Kabuto", "Orochimaru"};

    cout << "Taijutsu: " << taijutsu << endl;
    cout << "Ninjutsu: " << ninjutsu << endl;
    cout << "Eyes: " << eyes << endl;
    cout << "Chakra: " << chakra << endl;
    cout << "Summoning: " << summoning << endl;
    cout << "IQ: " << iq << endl;
    cout << "Speed: " << speed << endl;


}
```

I really need help on how to print random values from an array and assign it to a certain variable.

Comment: "assign it to a certain variable" what is "it"?

Comment: @JohnFilleau i want to take a random value from the array and print it.

Comment: So you don't want to "assign it to a certain variable"? Is that a typo? You only want to print a random element?

Comment: @JohnFilleau yeah